# How to Re-direct users by IP address except to a specific directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am testing a website before i make it live and i am using .htaccess to re-direct users by IP address to the Facebook Group Page while i finish the testing. We are 3 developers and i have been able to allow specific IP addresses to access the site.
However, i want to make a certain directory accessible by everyone. Please let me know how i can do that. This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^41\.210\.129\.
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^196\.0\.41\.54
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^41\.202\.225\.154 
RewriteRule .* http://www.facebook.com/groups/tradelinksafrica/ [R=302,L]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this RewriteCond: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder [NC]`